# Js immutable - how to flatten a map to a Set<number>

Tags: javascript, typescript, immutable.js

I have a value shipments that is of a type `Map<number, Shipment>`, Shipment has a property `packageIds` which is of a type `Set<number>`. When I have multiple shipments I would like to go through each shipment, get their `packageIds` and make a flat new Set with all of the `packageIds` from each shipment:

```
shipments.flatMap(shipment => shipment.get('packageIds'))
```

But, if I do that I get a typescript error:

```
TS2322: Type 'Set<number>' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<[unknown, unknown]>'.
  The types returned by '[Symbol.iterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types. 
  Type 'IteratorResult<number, any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<[unknown, unknown], any>'.       
  Type 'IteratorYieldResult<number>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<[unknown, unknown], any>'.         
  Type 'IteratorYieldResult<number>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult<[unknown, unknown]>'.           
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type '[unknown, unknown]'.
```

How can I then get a flat Set when iterating over a map?

Comment: Is `shipments` an array of maps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immutablejs [`flatMap` method of `Map`s](https://immutable-js.com/docs/v4.0.0/Map/#flatMap()) returns another `Map`. That's not what you want. [Convert to a `Set`](https://immutable-js.com/docs/v4.0.0/Map/#toSet()) before, discarding the `Map` keys:

```
shipments.toSet().flatMap(shipment => shipment.get('packageIds'))
```